# How to add exponentially increasing delay for each retry in Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-retry

Let's say I define two queues named `events` and `events.dlq`. Both queues are dead letter queues of each other.

As far as I understand, there are two ways to add delay to retry: (other than using plugin)

1- Adding `x-message-ttl` header while creating `events.dlq`. Thus, messages expired here go to `events` queue. The consumer then receives messages from the events queue.

*Disadvantage: It is impossible to change the `x-message-ttl` header within the rejected message. In other words, exponential increase functionality cannot be added in the message delay time.*

2- `BackoffOptions` value is defined in `RetryOperationsInterceptor` bean. Thus, a delay is added to the messages to be retried.

*Disadvantage: Since this delay is on the consumer side, the consumer is blocked throughout the delay. (in the first option, the message was expiring in the broker, in the second option, the delay is happening in the consumer)*

Here are the questions based on the above options:

**Question 1**: Is what I mentioned above true? If it is wrong, please correct.

**Question 2**: What is the most optimized way to add exponentially increasing delay for retry in a build with concurrent consumers?

Comment: if you don't need any custom mechanism you can use Spring Boot properties. Look for `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier` property in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: This is the easiest to implement, but a consumer-blocking solution. That is, if the interval is defined as 10 seconds, the consumer waits for 10 seconds for each retry.